# How to append a list of directories provided in a text file to PATH variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have a text file `list.txt` consisting of directories as follows.

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
C:\Program Files (x86)\cwRsync\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\PDF Labs\PDFtk Server\bin
```

I want to create a batch file that appends each item in `list.txt` to system `PATH` environment variable permanently.

My failed attempt is as follows.

```
rem batch.bat
for /f "delims=" %%x in (list.txt) do (setx PATH "%PATH%;%%x" /m)
```

I invoke `batch.bat` with administrative privilege but nothing appended to `PATH`. Could you help me solve it?

Comment: Note that `setx` doesn't affect the `cmd` session in which it is invoked.

Comment: If you add an echo, does it give a list of results that look right? `for /f "delims=" %%x in (list.txt) do (echo setx PATH "%PATH%;%%~x" /m)` ... I'm wondering what the %%~x gives

Comment: It means that the change to the variable you are modifying with `setx` cannot be seen in the same `cmd` that called that particular `setx`. But you can start another `cmd` session and the change will be reflected in it (provided the `setx` executed successfully).

Comment: From `setx /?`: `2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
         will be available in future command windows but not in the
         current CMD.exe command window.`

Comment: Do you have the path right for list.txt - does `for /f "delims=" %%x in (list.txt) do @echo %%x` actually list the file contents?

Comment: You should probably clarify what else your batch script is doing and/or how/where you want the new value of `PATH` to be used/reflected. Perhaps there is a solution that does not involve a manual extra CMD call.

Comment: Then maybe you shouldn't worry. Any new command window or other program that reads environment will see the new value. By "new (command window or program)" I mean one that starts *after* your script completes. To verify that the script works correctly, I would just run it, then start a new CMD and invoke PATH to see if the new paths were stored correctly. If everything was fine, I would just use it from then on. (And your script does seem fine to me, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
SET testvar=%PATH%
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (list.txt) DO (
CALL SET testvar=%%testvar%%%%x;
)
setx testvar "%testvar%"
```

Well - this sets 'testvar' for future invocations - I don't want to change my `PATH`; existing instances, including the current, will be unchanged (as documented.)

The problem with your implementation is that when a FOR loop is parsed, any `%var%` is replaced by its then-existing value before the loop is executed. In consequence, your command was executed as

```
setx path "(yourexistingpath);C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin"
setx path "(yourexistingpath);C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader"
...
```

which *should* have set your path according with the final line from your file (only) appended.

...and of course all you need to do to set `TESTVAR` in the CURRENT environment is to remove the `SETLOCAL` (which is actually only there to keep my environment clean while testing) OR to add a line

```
ENDLOCAL&set testvar=%testvar%
```

Comment: Whether you use the /M switch is of course a matter of choice. I chose not to use it.

Comment: Not a particularly informative response. Does `setx testvar somevalue` "work"? Remember - `SETX` will only set the value for `NEW` instances. What did you do to find out that "It does not work" ?

Comment: After invoking `echo %path%` from `cmd`  window as well as checking the PATH from the System Properties window, the PATH is unchanged. It is better if you test it in your machine as well.

Comment: Yes - ish. `setx var newvarvalue` sets `var` for all future CMD instances in your `current user session`. `Set var newvarvalue /m` sets var for `future` sessions - so you need to log off, then on again to see the change if you use /m...